# Format SQL DATETIME result like --> 8/25/2011 4:35 PM <-- NOT --> 2011-08-25 16:35:51.000 <--

Tags: sql, datetime, format

I have a SQL Query running on SQL Server 2008 R2 that returns a DATETIME column.  The current formatting returns this:

```
2011-08-25 16:35:51.000
```

and what I would rather see is this:

```
8/25/2011 4:35 PM
```

Ideas of how I can modify my SELECT statement?  Here a simple statement to work with...

```
SELECT DtCheckIn from Ticket
```

Thank you, Andrew

Comment: Formatting belongs in the user interface layer, _not_ in the database! Have the database give you the timestamp in a machine-friendly universal format (unix timestamp or whatever), and pass that unchanged through the business logic to your presentation code (which should be the only place that takes locale-related decisions like this).

Comment: I agree with Henning!  To do this you must change the data layer to return a [formatted] string, instead of a date.  Now the client application is getting a string characters that can only6 be displayed and nothing else. Format the string in the UI, only just before you need to display it to a human

Comment: Thanks for the input guys, and I agree as well.  Tricky thing is, the software this is going into has an option for 'Custom Reports' where you supply the SQL statement you want to query, and it returns it in a grid for the users.  Once I save the 'Custom Report', other users that rely on the report need to be able to read the data, and I can't change how the program processes it's data.  Weird I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 101) + RIGHT(convert(varchar, getdate(), 100), 7)
```

Resources on date time formatting:

http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/

EDIT - it's a little hokey but it should give you what you are looking for.

Basically the first part `SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 101)` gives you your date 08/25/2011.

The second part `SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 100)` gives you your date and time in the format `Aug 25 2011  5:35PM`.  You only want the time portion which is in the format `hh:mmAM` or `hh:mmPM` the total number of characters you want is 7. So if you change this to `SELECT RIGHT(convert(varchar, getdate(), 100), 8)` you will get your time   `5:37PM`. I used 8 in my `RIGHT()` to get an extra space. But now you only want your time not AM/PM so add SELECT LEFT(RIGHT(convert(varchar, getdate(), 100), 8), 6) and you will get your hh:mm.

Finally you want your AM/PM `SELECT RIGHT(convert(varchar, getdate(), 100), 2)` this will get you the last 2 characters.

Put it all together and you get:

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 101) 
    + LEFT(RIGHT(convert(varchar, getdate(), 100), 8), 6)
    + ' ' + RIGHT(convert(varchar, getdate(), 100), 2)
```

Which gives your final product:

```
08/25/2011  5:39 PM
```

Comment: I feel like this is a step in the right direction, with only two issues remaining:

1. If the time is in the 10, 11, or 12 hour, there is no space between the year and time

2. There is no space between the seconds and AM/PM

Any easy solutions?

Comment: I updated my answer with a new query and an explanation on how to get it.

Comment: So I went with this  --->   
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(26),DtCheckIn,101), 10) + ' ' + LEFT(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(26),DtCheckIn,109), 14), 8) + ' ' + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(26),DtCheckIn,109), 2) as [Checkin Date / Time] from Ticket

Comment: @bluefeet -- Just to let you know your clear concise answer is still helping in 2015.  -- Thank you!!